# Incorrect epoch conversion from datetime row in MySQL PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a stored row in my MySQL database that is a datetime row:

If I echo the value with PHP I get the following time in UTC:

```
2016-04-16 21:05:28
```

However, when I do the following I get the wrong epoch time according to epochconverter.com

```
$utc = $row['timestamp'];
$time = strtotime($utc);
```

The epoch value that I get is

```
1460833528
```

but it should be

```
1460862328
```

Comment: What timezone are you doing the calculation in, is it 8 hours diff from UTC

Comment: @RiggsFolly, no it is 6 hours diff from UTC

Comment: `strtotime` parameter(s) uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified. Use `strtotime( $utc.' UTC' )` or DateTime class. Side note: the unix timestamp for `2016-04-16 21:05:28` is `1460840728` (also on epochconverter.com).

Comment: @fusion3k, Thank you! this worked! What is the default time zone for strtotime?

Comment: Check the manual for strtotime(): `Each parameter of this function uses the default time zone unless a time zone is specified in that parameter. Be careful not to use different time zones in each parameter unless that is intended. See date_default_timezone_get() on the various ways to define the default time zone.`

Comment: Your timezone. I suppose CET (now CEST due to DST). UTC+1 (UTC+2 now)

Comment: @fusion3k, but PHP is server side so timezone of the php server?

Comment: yes. As per RiggsFolly comment, you can retrieve it using `date_default_timezone_get `. To set it you can use `date_default_timezone_set` or by editing php.ini file.